# adjust downbeat based on track

Tags: garage-band

I imported an MP3 into GarageBand 10 (Mac) but because it's just an MP3, GB has no sense of the tempo of the music I imported (it starts out 85BPM and stays there for all of two measures). I did go through and create an instrument track and found a good combination of snare and kick for a manual click track and it'd be great if there was a way to tell GB "all the snares on this track are the downbeats, and the kicks are internal beats" and have it map out the measures but I haven't found anything like that so far. I did see there's a tempo track but I'm sure I don't want to manually specify BPM for each measure.  Is there a way to line up the measure markers with a predefined set of downbeats?

Comment: what you’re describing is often called “beat detection.“ As far as I can tell garageband doesn’t have this feature, though some more advanced DHWs do. It’s not always totally reliable; some rhythm parts are more complex than a Sousa march. For your purposes it might be easiest to just figure out the tempo of the important track by hand and set it manually.

Comment: The tapped-out drum click isn't perfect but it's better than nothing. It's really just for a personal project so "good enough" is probably fine, was just hoping to have something a little easier to manage when I start doing edits.

Comment: This is definitely a feature in Logic Pro, not sure if it’s in GB. By the way, often the kick plays downbeats and snare plays upbeats, although not always. Just most of the time.

Comment: btw, please clarify: when you say "it starts out 85BPM and stays there for all of two measures," do you mean there's actually a tempo change in this track? Or that 85 is a close guess, and it takes two measures to realize that it's actually off? If the track is a (absolutely metronomic) steady tempo throughout, you just have to figure out that tempo and set it on the project. If it changes tempo, I'm not sure GarageBand can do that either.

Comment: It's not a steady tempo throughout - it's an orchestral backing track with (presumably) a live conductor pushing and pulling the tempo throughout the piece.

Comment: Ah. I haven't used it a lot, but I'm guessing an automatic beat detection feature won't give you very good results in that case. Though I think some programs will let you tap in the tempo as you listen, and you could perhaps use that to get the measure grid to align nicely.